# No screws on drywall near top plate?

Tags: drywall

I was reading some tips from a pro-drywaller and [he stated](https://www.protradecraft.com/what-could-cause-thousands-drywall-screw-pops) to not screw within 7" of the top plate when attaching wall rock.

> Do not screw into the top plate. Fasten walls about seven inches below the top plate. On the rare occasions that I have had screw pop problems, they were concentrated at along the top plate.

I was wondering if this has any science behind it? And doesn't it go against the installation instructions per building code and USG company? (8" to 12" on all edges)

Comment: Seems like a good article with good advice, but that one point is unsubstantiated. I'm having a hard time imagining the plates moving with respect to the studs.

Comment: I thought so too.  Everything else he stated makes sense and he has the experience to claim it....but this one confuses me.  I'm not sure what the basis is, because the two plates can not move vertically.  They are nailed together in many places and the weight of the roof pushes down constantly.

Comment: That article reads like someone, who "thinks" he figured "some" things out... so he decided to write about, because he was the first person, to ever do it that good, or at least as good as he thinks he his...

Answer (score 3):

**My assessment:** This guy drew an incorrect conclusion from one experience and has made a personal rule of it without good reason.

**My suggestion:** Disregard that advice. 99.9999% of all homes built with modern drywall have screws in the top plates. 99.9998% of the time it's not an issue.*

<sub>* 99.99999% of the statistics used in this post are fabricated.</sub>

Comment: + for the statistics.

Comment: So there's a chance you're wrong.

Comment: +1 In my area, it's not uncommon for the top row of every sheet, to be tacked up with nails, then screwed off, everywhere else. If he's popping at the top plate, he's sinking and breaking the rock, or his plates and studs don't line up - even then, there's some still leeway.

Answer (score 1):

If the bottom chord of the roof truss is fastened to the top plate, then humidity and load changes could cause the bottom chord to lift the top plate from the studs.  If this is the case, then I presume that you'd want to fasten the ceiling panels in a similar fashion to the wall panels.  In my house, I used drywall clips to fasten the edges of the ceiling panels to the top plate to mitigate the potential risk of truss chord uplift.

Search "Truss Uplift"

Answer (score 0):

I like that technique of not nailing to the top plates.

Show me a newly framed wall and I’ll show you that I can slide a piece of paper between the stud and the top plates. Those studs are not all cut EXACTLY the same length, plus those plates are not perfectly flat. ...then, let those studs dry for a few months and they’ll all shrink (and twist) different amounts.

THEN add a roof joist perpendicular to the wall and you’re asking for that wall framing to shrink when all that snow piles up. If the gyp board is fastened to the top plate, then something has to give.

The argument that the gyp board should be fastened at all edges isn’t practical either. Usually, the gyp board is not “blocked” so there’s nothing to fasten to at the 4’ height either.

Now, I have one exception: If it’s a shear wall (Yes, we use gyp board for shear) then it must be fastened to the top plates.